# how to add points to the end of the path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am adding circles, and for each circle I am adding a line with an animation that goes from the first circle to the final circle.

[image]

in my real problem I'm consuming a web service that returns a few points in x and y. with the help of a settimeout I am simulating when I use the web service and it returns points. I need to add a new or new points by creating a circle and doing an animation with the line that is created from the last circle to the new circle or the new circles without having to repeat the animation from the beginning, just animating the line from the last circle to new circles created. How can I do it?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/kvyr41Lw/

```
  var svg = d3.select('svg');

  var backLayer = svg.append("g");
  var frontLayer = svg.append("g");

  var dataSet = d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d * 30 + 10,
      y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
    }
  });

  var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y
    })
    .interpolate("monotone")

  function displayCircles(data) {
    var circle = frontLayer.selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr({
        r: 6,
        cx: function(d) {
          return d.x
        },
        cy: function(d) {
          return d.y
        },
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: "black",
        "stroke-width": "3px"
      });
  };

  function displayLine(data) {
    var line = backLayer.selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr({
        d: lineGenerator(data),
        fill: 'none',
        stroke: "red",
        "stroke-width": "3px"
      });

    var totalLength = line.node().getTotalLength();

    line.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
  }

  displayCircles(dataSet);
  displayLine(dataSet)
```

here I would need to simulate after a time that the web service returned me more points then they should be added and the line to have an animation from the last circle already created, until the last circle that will be created.

```
  setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("creating new points..")
  }, 5000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the displayCircles function for the new data and call displayCircles function 
by appending the new data to the last element of the dataSet array.

```
setTimeout(function() {
setInterval(function() {
var newData = { x: (dataSet.length) * 30 + 10, y: Math.random() * 130 + 10 
};
displayCircles([newData]);
displayLine([dataSet[dataSet.length - 1], newData]);
dataSet.push(newData);
}, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');

var backLayer = svg.append("g");
var frontLayer = svg.append("g");

var dataSet = d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
  return {
    x: d * 30 + 10,
    y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
  }
});

var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y
  })
  .interpolate("monotone")

function displayCircles(data) {
  var circle = frontLayer.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr({
      r: 6,
      cx: function(d) {
        return d.x
      },
      cy: function(d) {
        return d.y
      },
      fill: 'white',
      stroke: "black",
      "stroke-width": "3px"
    });
};

function displayLine(data) {
  var line = backLayer.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr({
      d: lineGenerator(data),
      fill: 'none',
      stroke: "red",
      "stroke-width": "3px"
    });

  var totalLength = line.node().getTotalLength();

  line.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
}

displayCircles(dataSet);
displayLine(dataSet)

setTimeout(function() {
 setInterval(function() {
 var newData = { x: (dataSet.length) * 30 + 10, y: Math.random() * 130 + 10 };
 displayCircles([newData]);
 displayLine([dataSet[dataSet.length - 1], newData]);
 dataSet.push(newData);
}, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

```css
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.8/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="800" height="800"></svg>
```

Comment: thanks friend!. I have a question, are existing lines overwritten or redrawn? or just create new lines when the circles are created ?, if all the default circles had zero opacity, would this work the same?

Comment: @yavg It won't redraw. It will draw a line from last point to the new point. You can try by giving zero opacity to circles

Comment: You really are a genius!
,Can you help me please with that please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407630/generation-of-lines-is-not-shown-attribute-d-of-the-path-is-empty