# generation of lines is not shown, attribute d of the path is empty

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create lines that connect and generate an animation.
I have an array of 2 positions, in each position of the array I want to generate a line from those points.

but my problem is that they are not generating, the attribute d of the path appears empty, that I am doing wrong?

[image]

this is my current code:
http://jsfiddle.net/6vhved46/

I made a modification to my original code which was this.

http://jsfiddle.net/syckujd8/

I changed the structure of the dataset variable on this occasion.

```
  var svg = d3.select('svg');

  var backLayer = svg.append("g");

  var dataSet=[
    [
      { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 30 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 30 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 30 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10}
    ],
     [
      { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 30 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 30 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 30 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 30 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10}

    ]
  ];
  console.log(dataSet);

  var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.corriente
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.voltaje
    })
    .interpolate("monotone")

  function displayLine(data) {
    var line = backLayer.selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d",function(d){
        lineGenerator(d)
      })
      .attr("fill",'none')
      .attr("stroke","red")
      .attr("stroke-width","1px")
      .attr("class","linea1");


    var totalLength = line.node().getTotalLength();

    line.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
  }

  displayLine(dataSet)
```

Comment: it should be return lineGenerator(d)

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi it works, but I have a problem with that.. the lines are very small comparated my last code. http://jsfiddle.net/8r86cfnr/   the lines are cutted in any cases https://i.imgur.com/KhGwwIK.jpg

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi only 2 paths are generated, in fact n paths should be generated by n number of lines. is what I believe

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi I want this to work as the previous code that you helped me to do, but with the new data structure.

Comment: displayLine([dataSet[0].concat(dataSet[1])])

Comment: @UmeshMaharshi you can post the answer please I'll give you the score and by the way help me answer this question please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410466/how-to-add-points-to-the-end-of-the-path-using-this-structure/46410993?noredirect=1#comment79780548_46410993