# Make multiple line with animation from the last position to the new positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my real problem I'm consuming a web service that returns an array with points in x and y. this is the structure of the array that I can receive.

```
  var dataSet=[
    [
      { "voltaje":  10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  40, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje": 70, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10}
    ],
     [
      { "voltaje": 100, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  130, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  160, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  190, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10}
    ]
  ];
```

I currently have this code that works for a structure like this:

```
var dataset=  [{
  x: d * 30 + 10,
  y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
},
{
  x: d * 30 + 10,
  y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
}
]
```

and in this code I get what I want. some lines are painted with an animation. and it is simulated as if the web service returns some points, then these new points are added and the animation of the line continues from the last point to the new point.

I want to have the points and the animation of each array separately, for example:

[image]

I would like to adapt my new structure to this code and make it separated to multiple lines, but I have not been able to. How can I do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/3ok8uuj3/

```
  var svg = d3.select('svg');

  var backLayer = svg.append("g");
  var frontLayer = svg.append("g");

  var dataSet = d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
    return {
      x: d * 30 + 10,
      y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
    }
  });

  var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y
    })
    .interpolate("monotone")

  function displayLine(data) {
    var line = backLayer.selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr({
        d: lineGenerator(data),
        fill: 'none',
        stroke: "red",
        "stroke-width": "3px"
      });

    var totalLength = line.node().getTotalLength();

    line.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
  }

  displayLine(dataSet)

  setTimeout(function() {
   setInterval(function() {
   var newData = { x: (dataSet.length) * 30 + 10, y: Math.random() * 130 + 10 };
   displayLine([dataSet[dataSet.length - 1], newData]);
   dataSet.push(newData);
  }, 2000);
  }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this that your are looking for?

There is a variable that stores the last data points for each series (if it exists, or create a new entry in the lastData array if there is no last data point for this series) and starts the new paths from these values. So even if you add new series of data, this should take care of creating a new line automatically.

Note: this uses D3.v4 (and not D3.v3 as in your example), since v3 is not maintained anymore.

```js
var svg = d3.select('svg');
var backLayer = svg.append("g");

//variable to store last data points the paths will have to start from
let lastData = []

//color scale
const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
 .domain([0, 1, 2])
  .range(["blue", "red", "green"])

//line generator
let lineGenerator = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.corriente
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.voltaje
    })
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)



function extractLastPoint(data){
  let lastDataPoint = []
  data.forEach(d => {
    lastDataPoint.push(d[d.length-1])
  })
  return lastDataPoint
}


function displayLine(data) {

  //adjust lastData array if discrepency of size
  if (lastData.length<data.length) {
    let diffSize = data.length - lastData.length
    let firstPos = data.length - diffSize

    for (let i=firstPos; i<data.length; i++){
      lastData.push(data[i][0])
    }
  }

  //add a path for each series and animate it
  data.forEach((d, i) => {

    d.unshift(lastData[i])

    let line = backLayer.append("path")
      .datum(d)
      .attr("d", p => lineGenerator(p))
      .attr("class", `line${i}`)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", colorScale(i))
      .attr("stroke-width", "3px") 
  
    let totalLength = line.node().getTotalLength();
  
    line
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
  })

  //save new last points of data to start next path from it
  lastData = extractLastPoint(data)
}


//initial line
let dataSet=[
      [
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10}
      ],
       [
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10}
      ]
    ]

  displayLine(dataSet)

//add new data every 3 sec
d3.interval(function() {
  let dataSet=[
      [
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10}
      ],
       [
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10},
        { "voltaje":  Math.random() * 200 + 10, "corriente": Math.random() * 550 + 10}
      ]
    ]

  displayLine(dataSet)

}, 3000)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="800" height="800"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

first the example without your data the data is

```
dataSet = [{x,y},{x,y}]
newData =  [last x and y, new data]
```

you want to change to

```
  var dataSet=[
    [
      { "voltaje":  10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  40, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje": 70, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10}
    ],
     [
      { "voltaje": 100, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  130, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  160, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  190, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10}
    ]
  ];

newData =  [last voltaje and corriente, new data]
```

create new data holder like `dataSet1`, `push` all new variable there, when redraw set the parameter to point on your data, you can use index, then draw it

```js
      var svg = d3.select('svg');

      var backLayer = svg.append("g");
      var frontLayer = svg.append("g");
  var dataSet=[
    [
      { "voltaje":  10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  40, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje": 70, "corriente": 30}
    ],
     [
      { "voltaje": 70, "corriente": 30},
      { "voltaje":  130, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  160, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  190, "corriente": 30}
    ],
         [
      { "voltaje": 190, "corriente": 30},
      { "voltaje":  160, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  200, "corriente": 30}
    ],
    
             [
      { "voltaje": 200, "corriente":30},
      { "voltaje":  130, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  160, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  190, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10}
    ]
  ];
  
  var dataSet1=[]
  console.log(dataSet[1][1])
  /*
      var dataSet = d3.range(1).map(function(d) {
        return {
          x: d * 30 + 10,
          y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
        }
      });
*/
      var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return d.voltaje
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return d.corriente
        })
        .interpolate("monotone")

      function displayLine(data) {
        var line = backLayer.selectAll(null)
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr({
            d: lineGenerator(data),
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: "red",
            "stroke-width": "3px"
          });

        var totalLength = line.node().getTotalLength();

        line.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
          .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
          .transition()
          .duration(2000)
          .ease("linear")
          .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
      }
  dataSet1.push(dataSet[0])
     displayLine(dataSet[0])
var i =0
var l = dataSet.length
console.log(i)
      setTimeout(function() {
  
       setInterval(function() {
      i++
       if (i<l){
       
       var newData = dataSet[i];
       }else{
       var newData = [{ 'voltaje': Math.random() * 30 + 10, 'corriente': Math.random() * 130 + 10 }]
       }
  console.log(i,newData,dataSet1,dataSet1[i-1] )
       newData.unshift(dataSet1[i-1][dataSet1[i-1].length - 1])
         displayLine(newData);;
       dataSet1.push(newData);
      }, 2000);
 
      }, 2000);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="800" height="800"></svg>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! you almost made it, but just a second before you wrote your answer, I tried to be a little clearer. I was actually trying to explain that I need the lines to be independent.

Comment: as in the image..when I add more points in some position of the array I would like to make the animation of lines from the last position to the new positions. I hope you can help me. I would thank you in the soul

Comment: I think the title is something more specific, I thank you for correcting it. seeing your code I still have the same problem, my knowledge in d3.js are not enough for what I need. I think you already understand what I need. I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this, you must simple it i make it not simple cos i want you understand, it can make with single svg if you know the min max value of axis, but i doing on 3 svg i hope you can learn and make it what you want

```js
var dataSet=[
    [
      { "voltaje":  10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  40, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10}
    ],
         [
      { "voltaje":  10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje":  40, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10},
      { "voltaje": 50, "corriente": 30}
    ],
            [
      { "voltaje":  10, "corriente": Math.random() * 130 + 10}
    ],
  ];
  
  dataSet.forEach(function(d,i){
     var svg = d3.select('#dataset'+(i+1));
      var backLayer = svg.append("g").attr('id','back'+i);
      var frontLayer = svg.append("g").attr('id','front'+i);
  })
  var dataSet1=[]
  var dataSet2=[]
  var dataSet3=[]
  console.log(dataSet[1][1])
  /*
      var dataSet = d3.range(1).map(function(d) {
        return {
          x: d * 30 + 10,
          y: Math.random() * 130 + 10
        }
      });
*/


      function displayLine(data,svg,i) {
      
      var lineGenerator = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return d.voltaje
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return d.corriente
        })
        .interpolate("monotone")
        var line = d3.select('#back'+i).selectAll(null)
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr({
            d: lineGenerator(data),
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: "red",
            "stroke-width": "3px"
          });

        var totalLength = line.node().getTotalLength();

        line.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
          .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
          .transition()
          .duration(2000)
          .ease("linear")
          .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
      }
      
      
    dataSet.forEach(function(d,i){
      if (i==0){
      var data = dataSet1
      
      }else if(i==1){
      var data = dataSet2
      }else{
      var data = dataSet3
      }
       var svg = d3.select('#dataset'+(i+1));
     data.push(dataSet[i])
      displayLine(dataSet[i],svg,i)
    })
 
var i1=(-1)
var i2=(-1)
var i3=(-1)
var t = 1
      setTimeout(function() {
 
       setInterval(function() {
       t++
     dataSet.forEach(function(d,i){
    var newData = [{ 'voltaje': 10 + 50*t + 100, 'corriente': Math.random() * 130 + 10*1 }]
     if (i==0){
      i1++
      var data = dataSet1
       newData.unshift(data[i1][data[i1].length - 1])
       console.log(i,data[i])
      }else if(i==1){
      i2++
      var data = dataSet2
       newData.unshift(data[i2][data[i2].length - 1])
       console.log(i,data[i])
      }else{
      i3++
      var data = dataSet3
       newData.unshift(data[i3][data[i3].length - 1])
       console.log(i,data[i])
      }
     
      
      var svg = d3.select('#dataset'+(i+1));
       displayLine(newData,svg,i);
       data.push(newData);
      })

      }, 2000);
 
      }, 2000);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
svg{
display:block;
}
body {
  background: #ffd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200" id='dataset1'></svg>
<svg width="500" height="200" id='dataset2'></svg>
<svg width="500" height="200" id='dataset3'></svg>
```